# Internet Explorer problem - runtime error

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, scripting

when i am going through my project in IE only its showing errors

A runtime error has occurred Do you wish to debug?

Line 768
Error:Expected')'

Is this is regarding any script error

Comment: You're going to have to give us *a lot* more than that - What file is that? What's the code around line 768? What event triggers this (load, click, postback...)?

Comment: click event,,i think some script error let me check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it looks like you have a javascript syntax error. Check unclosed paranthesis and unclosed string literals in your client script blocks.

Comment: means in that line 768,,i think let me check

Comment: It may not be in the line 768. sometimes it throws errors near the line it warns. because your other paranthesises covers the expected one. check the possible methods you newly added.

Comment: Or click debug at the debug message, and select Visual studio in the list. it shows you the position of the error.

Comment: but i didnt find any script in that page

Comment: do you have external js files attached to page ?

Comment: we used two pages that js files like

  <script type="text/javascript" src="../Includes/JS/jquery-1.2.6-vsdoc.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="../Includes/JS/jquery-1.2.6.js"></script>.....etc

Comment: yes 6 js files are using,,how to know that which one is producing problems

Comment: Click OK when it asks you if you want to debug. and in the list select Visual Studio. it will place the cursor to the line that produce error.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.jonathanboutelle.com/mt/archives/2006/01/howto_debug_jav.html) might be helpful for javascript debugging in Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

use firefox + firebug , your JS errors will be a thing of the past ;)

Comment: means we can see js from firebug addons

Answer (score 0):

One of the common reasons for this could be the unescaped quotes inside the string parameter of javascript handler, such as:

onmouseover='myJavascriptFun("my so called "parameter"")'

For some reason IE unlike for example FF unescapes quotes before parsing javascript, so the code above becomes

onmouseover='myJavascriptFun("my so called "parameter"")'

so the ')' is expected after the second ".

The parameter, of course, comes from a data source so it should have been escaped using htmlentities or such method.